# Find the p-value

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm strugling tyring to find the p-value if i'm given a Ho Ha and z-statistic.. Also I need to consider if it is one side or two sides...

So for example find the p-value:

```
 z-statistic = 2.80
     Ho: π = 0.10
     Ha: π ≠ 0.10.
```

I guess i'm looking for steps or what to plug into the calc.

Comment: Try searching and reading *more* and see different examples about p-value computation!

Comment: Hint: when $\pi \neq 0.1$ does it mean $\pi < 0.1$ or $\pi > 0.1$ or both?

Comment: You need to tell us more. Use of the letter $\pi$ suggests this is a problem involving the binomial distribution.  If so, are you doing an exact test using binomial probabilities to get the P-value? Or is this a problem in which using a normal approximation is expected.?